# Geolocation Not Working

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am new to app development with cordova. I want to build an app using geolocation. I have added necessary plugin and I followed official documentation. But when I run the app on my device it doesn't show anything. I have location enabled on my device

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError);
    }

    var onSuccess = function(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                            'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                            'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                            'Timestamp: '          + position.timestamp                    + '<br />';
    }

    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write:

```
var geolocationSuccess = function(position) {....
```

or

```
navigator.globalization.getCurrentPosition(
    function(position) { .... },
    function(error) { .... }
);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. I did what you said but it still doesn't work. On device it only shows the primary html (Finding geolocation...). It doesn't show location information that the javascript code should do.